# Mathf.Lerp slows at the end

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making basic character movement with Character Controller and Input System in Unity. When player is standing up from crouching, it`s slow. How to fix it?

```
private void Update()
    {
        _isGrounded = _characterController.isGrounded;
        
        if (_lerpCrouch)
        {
            _crouchTimer += Time.deltaTime;
            float t = _crouchTimer / 1;
            t *= t;

            _characterController.height = Mathf.Lerp(_characterController.height, _isCrouching ? 1 : 2, t);

            if (t >= 1)
            {
                _lerpCrouch = false;
                _crouchTimer = 0;
            }
        }
    }
......
public void Crouch()
    {
        _isCrouching = !_isCrouching;
        _crouchTimer = 0;
        speed = _isCrouching ? crouchSpeed : walkSpeed;
        _lerpCrouch = true;
    }
```

I have tried to do SmoothDamp but it works the same. Currently player is just a capsule.  _characterController.height achieves 2 when stand, it just the whole process of standing up looks like in low fps (when in relity it`s okay)

Answer (score 0):

you interpolate always from the current height towards a target

=> The closer you get to the current height the smaller the step of course.

If you want to go with `Lerp` and achieve a linear interpolation you would rather need to cache the initial height and interpolate over

```
_characterController.height = Mathf.Lerp(initialHeight, _isCrouching ? 1 : 2, t);
```

Alternatively you could use

```
 _characterController.height = Mathf.MoveTowards( _characterController.height, _isCrouching ? 1 : 2, Time.deltaTime);

 if(Mathf.Approximately(_characterController.height, _isCrouching ? 1 : 2))
 {
     ...
 }
```

---

I would recommend a Coroutine

```
private Coroutine crouchRoutine;

public void Crouch()
{
    _isCrouching = !_isCrouching;
    speed = _isCrouching ? crouchSpeed : walkSpeed;

    if(crouchRoutine != null) StopCoroutine(crouchRoutine);
    crouchRoutine = StartCoroutine(CrouchRoutine());
} 

private IEnumerator CrouchRoutine()
{
    var currentHeight = _characterController.height;
    var targetHeight = _isCrouching ? 1 : 2;

    var duration = 1 - Mathf.InverseLerp(_isCrouching ? 2 : 1, targetHeight, currentHeight);

    for(var time = 0f; time < duration; time += Time.deltaTime)
    {
        var factor = time / duration;
        _characterController.height = Mathf.Lerp(currentHeight, targetHeight, factor);

        yield return null;
    }

    _characterController.height = targetHeight;
    crouchRoutine = null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have added _initialHeight but result is the same as it was. Am I doing it wrong? Lines 44 and 102. https://pastebin.com/GKXWWWq3

Comment: here is video https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kMsTAZUiyWo4SBSlnQ_WgoohiRzQJ1iE/view?usp=sharing